# como obtener los valores de variables parametrizadas de un config.properties en java?

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo un mvn project, tengo el config.properties en los resources y quiero llamarlo en el main

```
public class GetProperties {
    private Properties prop = new Properties();

    public GetProperties() {

    InputStream in = 
    getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");


try {
  prop.load(in);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("The property file was not found");
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("Can not read property file");
}
}

  public String getPropValues( String propertyName){
  return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
   }
  }
```

Ese es mi clase GetProperties, pero me da Null Pointer Exception

Comment: hola szito, estas seguro que el archivo .properties esta en la raíz del proyecto y se llama config.properties

Comment: hola @Jorgesys, si estoy seguro, esta adentro del proyecto, pero por algun motivo no lo encuentra

Comment: Obtienes NullPointerException u otro error? realiza un clean del proyecto y comenta resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si obtienes `NullPointerException` es porque el archivo no se encuentra, este debe encontrarse en la raíz del proyecto ("/config.properties"). Asegura que el nombre sea el que tienes definido: `config.properties`.

Utiliza `ClassLoader` como contexto para usar `getResourceAsStream()`

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();           
InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

Comment: No estaba especificando bien la direccion del archivo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: @szito por eso NullPointerException, excelente, saludos!